# Error Expected value of type '(String, dynamic)

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm a new flutter user. here I make a search using api, but when I want to search for a word then the data does not appear on the listview page. even though the json already looks like this on the debug console

```
          {
            "konten_gambar": null,
            "konten_gambar2": null,
            "konten_gambar3": null,
            "konten_deskripsi": null,
            "konten_syarat": null,
            "konten_ketentuan": null,
            "konten_fasilitas": null,
            "konten_promosi_gambar": null,
            "konten_promosi_text": null,
            "konten_sk": null,
            "konten_status": null,
            "konten_update": null,
            "konten_approval": null,
            "konten_url": "/danakonven",
            "file_path": null,
            "konten_deskripsi2": null,
            "konten_deskripsi3": null,
            "file_path2": null,
            "file_path3": null
        },
```

and here I get an error like the following

```
Expected a value of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>', but got one of type '(dynamic) => SearchModel$'
```

is there something wrong with the MODEL that I made, please ask for help friends

here is my source code

**model.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<SearchModel> searchModelFromJson(String str) => List<SearchModel>.from(
    // ignore: always_specify_types
    json.decode(str).map((x) => SearchModel.fromJson(x)));

String searchModelJson(List<SearchModel> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((SearchModel x) => x.toJson())));

class SearchModel {
  SearchModel({
    this.kontenId,
    this.kontenParent,
    this.kontenUrut,
    this.kategoriId,
    this.kontenSimulasi,
    this.kontenSukuBunga,
    required this.kontenMenu,
    this.kontenJudul,
    this.kontenSubjudul,
    this.kontenGambar,
    this.kontenGambar2,
    this.kontenGambar3,
    this.kontenDeskripsi,
    this.kontenSyarat,
    this.kontenKetentuan,
    this.kontenFasilitas,
    this.kontenPromosiGambar,
    this.kontenPromosiText,
    this.kontenSk,
    this.kontenStatus,
    this.kontenUpdate,
    this.kontenApproval,
    this.kontenUrl,
    this.filePath,
    this.kategoriNama,
  });
  factory SearchModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SearchModel(
        kontenId: json['konten_id'],
        kontenParent: json['konten_parent'],
        kontenUrut: json['konten_urut'],
        kategoriId: json['kategori_id'],
        kontenSimulasi: json['konten_simulasi'],
        kontenSukuBunga: json['konten_suku_bunga'],
        kontenMenu: json['konten_menu'],
        kontenJudul: json['konten_judul'],
        kontenSubjudul: json['konten_subjudul'],
        kontenGambar: json['konten_gambar'],
        kontenGambar2: json['konten_gambar2'],
        kontenGambar3: json['konten_gambar3'],
        kontenDeskripsi: json['konten_deskripsi'],
        kontenSyarat: json['konten_syarat'],
        kontenKetentuan: json['konten_ketentuan'],
        kontenFasilitas: json['konten_fasilitas'],
        kontenPromosiGambar: json['konten_promosi_gambar'],
        kontenPromosiText: json['konten_promosi_text'],
        kontenSk: json['konten_sk'],
        kontenStatus: json['konten_status'],
        kontenUpdate: json['konten_update'],
        kontenApproval: json['konten_approval'],
        kontenUrl: json['konten_url'],
        filePath: json['file_path'],
        kategoriNama: json['kategori_nama'],
      );

  dynamic kontenId;
  dynamic kontenParent;
  dynamic kontenUrut;
  dynamic kategoriId;
  dynamic kontenSimulasi;
  dynamic kontenSukuBunga;
  String kontenMenu;
  dynamic kontenJudul;
  dynamic kontenSubjudul;
  dynamic kontenGambar;
  dynamic kontenGambar2;
  dynamic kontenGambar3;
  dynamic kontenDeskripsi;
  dynamic kontenSyarat;
  dynamic kontenKetentuan;
  dynamic kontenFasilitas;
  dynamic kontenPromosiGambar;
  dynamic kontenPromosiText;
  dynamic kontenSk;
  dynamic kontenStatus;
  dynamic kontenUpdate;
  dynamic kontenApproval;
  dynamic kontenUrl;
  dynamic filePath;
  dynamic kategoriNama;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'konten_id': kontenId,
        'konten_parent': kontenParent,
        'konten_urut': kontenUrut,
        'kategori_id': kategoriId,
        'konten_simulasi': kontenSimulasi,
        'konten_suku_bunga': kontenSukuBunga,
        'konten_menu': kontenMenu,
        'konten_judul': kontenJudul,
        'konten_subjudul': kontenSubjudul,
        'konten_gambar': kontenGambar,
        'konten_gambar2': kontenGambar2,
        'konten_gambar3': kontenGambar3,
        'konten_deskripsi': kontenDeskripsi,
        'konten_syarat': kontenSyarat,
        'konten_ketentuan': kontenKetentuan,
        'konten_fasilitas': kontenFasilitas,
        'konten_promosi_gambar': kontenPromosiGambar,
        'konten_promosi_text': kontenPromosiText,
        'konten_sk': kontenSk,
        'konten_status': kontenStatus,
        'konten_update': kontenUpdate,
        'konten_approval': kontenApproval,
        'konten_url': kontenUrl,
        'file_path': filePath,
        'kategori_nama': kategoriNama,
      };
}
```

**apiservice.dart**

```
class SearchService {
  Future<SearchModel> searchMenu(String kontenMenu) async {
    try {
      final String apiUrl = '${baseUrl}search/$kontenMenu';
      final http.Response response = await httpClient.get(
        Uri.parse(apiUrl),
        // ignore: always_specify_types
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
      );

      debugPrint(response.body);

      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
        // ignore: always_specify_types
        final it = json.decode(response.body);
        final List<SearchModel> list =
            // ignore: always_specify_types
            it.map((item) => SearchModel.fromJson(item))[0].toList();
```

Comment: Check what is the result if you print the `SearchModel.fromJson(item))[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

```
 final List<SearchModel> list =
            // ignore: always_specify_types
            it.map((item) => SearchModel.fromJson(item))[0].toList();
```

Change this to this:

```
  if(response.body != null){

     final List<SearchModel> list = searchModelFromJson(response.body);
}
```

Remove this Line:

```
 final it = json.decode(response.body);
```

You dont need to decode it as searchModelFromJson() this method will decode and map the value